# Add "appointment" to calendar launching Uri schemes

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uri-scheme

You can use Uri Schemes to Launch another apps to manage requests, for example to make a telephone call:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("tel: " + number));
```

I need use calendar Uri schemes to add an appointment to Calendar (day, hour and title) in UWP App, but I have no idea which is the standar Uri scheme for calendar, if exist.

Another option is use "Outlookcal" to launch Outlook (instead of use standar uri scheme), but I not able to find to syntaxis to add an appointment with day, hour and title, I only know how launch Outlook Calendar:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("outlookcal:"));
```

Anyone knows how use calendar Uri scheme to add an appointment, or add an appointment with Outlookcal Uri scheme?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use URI scheme (it does not seem documented anywhere). It is possible to create appointments [directly using the UWP API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments).

```
//create appointment
var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();

// ... set its properties
appointment.StartTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
appointment.Subject = "Meeting subject";
appointment.Details = "Meeting description";

//show popup to add to calendar
string appointmentId = 
   await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(
                         appointment, 
                         rect, 
                         Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default );
```

Comment: This is a good alternative if nobody knows how to use the uri schemes, thx!

Comment: I have looked around and it does not seem that there is an alternative now. There seems to be no standardized URI scheme for this :-(

Answer (score 0):

i find a way to satisfy your requirement.
the method i used like follow:

`Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("outlookcal:addevent?start=xxx&end=xxx&subject=xxx")`

through the command above,i open the add new event page directly with start time,end time and the subject.
but i have not find the arguments to speicify the desciptions of the event.i have used "body","message","descriptions","content" and others.but these all doesn't work.i really want to know the arguments to specify the decription of the event.